# “Except” Meaning-in-Context

Tags: meaning-in-context

Did people in the early 1900s say things like “don’t *except* too much” or was this a mistake? Please look at sentence #4 below for context, which states:

“Don’t except too much, most men are lazy, selfish, thoughtless, lying, drunken, clumsy, heavy-footed, rough, unmanly brutes, and need taming.”

I saw this posted on Twitter and people were discussing if it was a mistake (instead of “accept”) or if the word “expect” was intended.

[image: 1918 Suffragette poster on Marriage Advice for Young Ladies]

I found a CFR example [here](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/45/146.145).

[image: Code of Federal Regulations example]

When I attempted to come up with a sentence that made sense (with a similar meaning-in-context, if not a mistake), I wrote:

.

I appreciate your interest in this—- thank you ☺️

Comment: The first one is a typo for _expect_. The second one is legal language and intended to confuse.

Comment: What @JohnLawler said. In the legal example, *excepted* means *excluded*.

Comment: Also, that supposedly 1918 document is clearly a modern imitation, poorly conceived and poorly executed.